# Testing a function in a react component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I'm pretty new to unit testing with react components. I have a react component that copies the given id from props when clicked. And that's calling a function from a separate file to execute a copyToClipboard function and then set the state of a react component to 'copied'. I'm trying to test test these functions and possibly get the state value changed to 'copied'. Whenever i try to simulate the onclick function, it gives an error saying 'Cannot read property 'writeText' of undefined'. It's because onClick function is calling a seperate function for this process, is it possible to mock that other function and pass that to onClick() function or another solution? Or any pointers how i should move forward?

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {copyToClipboard} from './CopyFile'
export default function App({id}) {
  const [copyStatus, setCopyStatus] = useState('')

  const copyLineItemId=(id)=>{
    copyToClipboard(id)
    setCopyStatus('Copied')
    setTimeout(function () {
      setCopyStatus('')
    }, 2000)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <i id="copy" className="fa fa-copy" onClick={() =>copyLineItemId({id})}></i>
      <p id="status">{copyStatus}</p>
  </div>
  );
}
```

Test file

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing'

function getComponent(props) {
  const { componentProps } = props
  return (
    <MockedProvider>
      <CopyComponent {...componentProps} />
    </MockedProvider>
  )
}


test('copy function', () => {
    const componentProps = {
      id:123
    }

    const wrapper = mount(getComponent({ componentProps }))

    wrapper.find("#copy").simulate('click')

    expect(wrapper.find("#status")).toEqual("Copied")
  })
```

copy function CopyFile.js

```
const copyToClipboard = (arg) => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(arg)
}

export {copyToClipboard}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSdom the `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` is not defined, so you have to define it yourself, like so:

```
Object.assign(navigator, {
  clipboard: {
    writeText: () => {},
  },
});
```